# Regex query to validate a currency string C#?

Tags: c#, regex, validation, currency-formatting

I am in no way a master of `Regex` which is why I am here I currently have this:

```regex
\s?[^0-9]?\s?[0-9,]+([\\.]{1})?[0-9]+\s?
```

[Link](https://regex101.com/r/oQ9xC5/1) to regex101

To explain my validation attempt I am trying to validate that a string matches the correct formatting structure.

I only want to **match** strings such as:

> - £1.00
> - £10.00
> - £100.00
> - £1000.00
> - £10,000.00
> - £100,000.00
> - £1,234,546.00

**Validation rules**:

- String must include a '£' at the start.
- String should always have 2 digits following a decimal place.
- Following the '£' only digits between 0-9 should be accepted
- If the string length is greater than 6 (after £1000.00) then commas need to be entered at the appropriate points (I.E. £10,000.00 - £100,000.00 - £1,000,000.00 - £10,000,000.00 etc)

For example, strings that **shouldn't** be accepted:

> - £1
> - £10.000
> - £1,00.00
> - £1,000.00
> - 10,000.00
> - £100,000,00
> - £1.234.546

Really hoping that one of you amazing people can help me out, if you need anymore info then please let me know!

Comment: Is there a reason for those specific validation rules? It seems like you could use [`decimal.TryParse(string. System.Globalization.NumberStyles, IFormatProvider, out decimal)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse) instead of a regex. Most of your examples that you say should fail are going to succeed if you do that, but I'm not sure why that would be a problem. For example, why should `£1` fail? Shouldn't that just be `£1.00`? And shouldn't `£10.000` just be `£10.00`?

Comment: The validation rules are work-related if the test data shows a string of  `£1` as the fund value then it shows that there is an issue with the formatting and this needs to be reflected in the automated tests.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
new Regex(@"£\d{1,3}(\,\d{3})*\.\d{2}\b");
```

Edit:

```
new Regex(@"£((\d{1,4})|(\d{2,3}(\,\d{3})+)|(\d(\,\d{3}){2,}))\.\d{2}\b");
```

https://regex101.com/r/zSRw2B/1

Comment: This is soooo close to what I need. [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Jsbyly/1)

Just the £1000.00 that is matching wrong. It should match £1000.00 and not £1,000.00. Would you be able to change it for me to match that instead? @alex-dl

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [pattern below](https://regex101.com/r/XwqoNI/1):

```
  ^£(?:[0-9]{1,4}|[0-9]{2,3},[0-9]{3}|[0-9]{1,3}(?:,[0-9]{3}){2,})\.[0-9]{2}$
```

When pences are *mandatory* - `\.[0-9]{2}` we have **3** options for pounds:

```
  [0-9]{1,4}                   for sums in range £0 .. £9999
  [0-9]{2,3},[0-9]{3}          for sums in range £10,000 .. £999,999
  [0-9]{1,3}(?:,[0-9]{3}){2,}  for huge sums     £1,000,000 ..
```

**Demo:**

```
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  ...

  Regex regex = new Regex(
    @"^£(?:[0-9]{1,4}|[0-9]{2,3},[0-9]{3}|[0-9]{1,3}(?:,[0-9]{3}){2,})\.[0-9]{2}$";

  string[] tests = new string[] {
    "£1.00",
    "£10.00",
    "£100.00",
    "£1000.00",
    "£10,000.00",
    "£100,000.00",
    "£1,234,546.00",

    "£1",
    "£10.000",
    "£1,00.00",
    "£1,000.00",
    "10,000.00",
    "£100,000,00",
    "£1.234.546",
  };

  string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
    .Select(test => $"{test,15} : {(regex.IsMatch(test) ? "Match" : "Fail")}"));

  Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
          £1.00 : Match
         £10.00 : Match
        £100.00 : Match
       £1000.00 : Match
     £10,000.00 : Match
    £100,000.00 : Match
  £1,234,546.00 : Match
             £1 : Fail
        £10.000 : Fail
       £1,00.00 : Fail
      £1,000.00 : Fail
      10,000.00 : Fail
    £100,000,00 : Fail
     £1.234.546 : Fail
```

Comment: You sir are a god! Do you by chance know a good place that I can read up on Regex I would love to be able to use it properly but the sytax is just foreign to me?

Comment: @HermanCodes: There are many regex tutorials, e.g. https://regexone.com/

Comment: Thank you so much, I would up-vote you if I could :D